# How to get macros usage not included in Rust code overage?

Tags: rust

I have the following pipeline on GitHub actions that I use in pair with Codecov to monitor code coverage.

```yaml
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          lfs: true

      - uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
        with:
          toolchain: nightly
          override: true
   
      - uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          command: test        
        args: --all-features
        env:
          CARGO_INCREMENTAL: '0'
          RUSTFLAGS: '-Zprofile -Ccodegen-units=1 -Cinline-threshold=0 -Clink-dead-code -Coverflow-checks=off -Cpanic=abort -Zpanic_abort_tests -Cinstrument-coverage'
          RUSTDOCFLAGS: '-Zprofile -Ccodegen-units=1 -Cinline-threshold=0 -Clink-dead-code -Coverflow-checks=off -Cpanic=abort -Zpanic_abort_tests -Cinstrument-coverage'
      
      - uses: actions-rs/grcov@v0.1
        id: coverage
        name: Generate code coverage

      - name: Upload to codecov.io
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v3
        with:
          files: ${{ steps.coverage.outputs.report }}
          token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
```

The code coverage Github integration shows the current code as not covered.

```
#[derive(Error, Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum EncodingFormatParsingError {
    #[error("Unexpected encoding {0}")] // line not covered
    UnexpectedEncoding(String),
}
```

How can I get macro to be covered ?

Comment: I haven't done this myself, so I don't know if it would work, but have you tried the [alternative code-coverage implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/instrument-coverage.html)?

Comment: I added  -Cinstrument-coverage to use instrument coverage. What alternative implementations do you have in mind?

Comment: I'm guessing you might need to use a different tool to parse the coverage results generated by that flag, since I understand the `grcov` tool makes use of the `-Zprofile` results, not the `-Cinstrument-coverage` results